# 500 error caused by Doctrine 2 DBAL query

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have this query:

```
public function warnBelowCostPrices(Application $app) {
        $em = $app['orm.em'];

        ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 3);
        ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 40);

        try {
        //basic option check
        $optionQuery = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT o FROM m:Option o JOIN m:Product p
            WHERE o.costPriceVariation > 0 AND o.price > 0 AND o.stock > 0
            AND (o.costPriceVariation >= o.price OR p.costPrice >= o.price)
        ');
        $options = $optionQuery->getResult();
        //var_dump($options);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e);
            die();
    }
```

Which is causing a 500 error. This is the only code executed in the call I am testing and nothing appears in the logs.

Can anyone see why this would occur?

Answer (score 0):

OK worked this out

```
SELECT o FROM m:Option o JOIN m:Product p
```

should be

```
SELECT o FROM m:Option o JOIN o.product
```

I thought it was implied that I wanted the second approach, but apparently I have to explicitly state it.